# spring data jpa query value in a Set

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity class A which has a Set of entities of class B with a ManyToMany relationship (out of scope why I need this)

```
class A {

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    Set<B> setOfB;
}
```

Now, given an object of class B, how can I retrieve the object(s) of class A which has the B object in its Set??

I have tried in my class A repository with this:

```
interface Arepository extends JpaRepository<A, Long> {

    @Query("from A a where ?1 in a.setOfB")
    List<A> findByB(B b)
}
```

But it gives me a SQLGrammarException, so which is the correct syntax?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you try `@Query("from A a where ?1 member of a.setOfB")`?

Comment: You saved my day... you see I am not very verse in SQL as you might have understood... thank you very much
EDIT:
crap... I have upvoted your comment but by mistakes I have undone it and now it does not let me upvote it again!!! Really sorry, how can I upvote you again?

Comment: Oops, you've missed off "SELECT a" off the start of that JPQL query. After all JPQL cannot start "FROM" as the JPA spec says

Comment: @NeilStockton really? I know that in a SQL query I have to have select, of course, but with spring there are cases where I can omit it, and it works. For example, the query suggested by Predrag works without 'select'... mind you I am passing the parameter as in ":b" [findBy(@Param("b")B b)] and not ?1

Comment: JPQL != SQL. JPQL != HQL. You marked your question as JPA, not Hibernate (or HQL), so no it would not work in *other* JPA implementations, and any documentation that purports to be for JPQL should ALWAYS have "SELECT {alias}" (as does the JPA spec)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try with `@Query("SELECT a from A a where ?1 member of a.setOfB")`.

Comment: I also not aware about member of because i always used specification for such data retrieval.

Comment: It is in [JPA specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-oth-JSpec/), check out section 4.6.13

Comment: @HarshalPatil just out of curiosity, how do you do it?

Comment: @Johnny i used to write predicate using specifications for that.

Answer (score 0):

Metamodel class:

```
@Generated(value = "org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor")
@StaticMetamodel(A.class)
public class A_ {
    public static volatile SetAttribute<A, B> bSet;
}
```

Specification utils:

```
public class ASpecs {

    public static Specification<A> containsB(B b) {
        return (root, query, cb) -> {
            Expression<Set<B>> bSet = root.get(A_.bSet);
            return cb.isMember(b, bSet);
        };
    }
}
```

Your repository:

```
public interface ARepository extends JpaRepository<A, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<A> {
}
```

Usage:

```
@Service
public class YourService {

    @Resource
    private ARepository repository;

    public List<A> getByB(B b) {
        return repository.findAll(ASpecs.containsB(b));
    }
}
```